# Should I write “in my project” or “for my project”?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What is the correct preposition to use in the following sentence?

> I found some information on the Internet and I used it {in/for} my project.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct but mean different things.  The correct answer depends on what you want to say.

> I found some information on the Internet and I used it in my project.

The information is likely now actually part of the project - it might be cited, referenced, adapted, or otherwise physically part of the project.  The project is a "container" and the information is now "in" it.

> I found some information on the Internet and I used it for my project.

The information helped you complete the project, but the information itself isn't part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

That is a hard one.  "Used in my project" could imply the information helped to supplement other information that was also used.  "Used for my project" could mean the same thing or it could mean it formed the basis for the entire project.